# Promela randomly select two elements at the same time

Tags: model, promela, spin

Recently I started learning Promela and I want to model picking two balls from box where I have 10 black balls and 4 white balls, I can model box as array, but I have no idea how to select 2 balls at the same time. Picking one and then another one from those which are left changes probability. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to extract **only** a pair of values `idx` and `idy` from a contiguous interval `[LOW, UPP]` of `N = UPP - LOW + 1` numbers, you can easily get around the problem of guaranteeing `idx != idy` by:

- picking `idx` in `[LOW, UPP]`
- picking `idy` in `[LOW, UPP - 1]`
- adjusting the value of `idy` wrt. the value of `idx` as follows:

  ```
  idy = LOW + (((idx - LOW) + 1 + (idy - LOW)) % N)
  ```

that is, you interpret `idy` as a fixed displacement wrt. `idx`. Notice that this approach does not affect the probability distribution of `idy` and, in particular, it does not make `idy` dependent on `idx` from a probabilistic point of view.

---

**Example:**

```cpp
#define BLACK_BALLS 4
#define WHITE_BALLS 10
#define TOTAL_BALLS 14

bool box[TOTAL_BALLS];

inline my_select(var, upper) {
    if
        ::  0 <= upper -> var =  0;
        ::  1 <= upper -> var =  1;
        ::  2 <= upper -> var =  2;
        ::  3 <= upper -> var =  3;
        ::  4 <= upper -> var =  4;
        ::  5 <= upper -> var =  5;
        ::  6 <= upper -> var =  6;
        ::  7 <= upper -> var =  7;
        ::  8 <= upper -> var =  8;
        ::  9 <= upper -> var =  9;
        :: 10 <= upper -> var = 10;
        :: 11 <= upper -> var = 11;
        :: 12 <= upper -> var = 12;
        :: 13 <= upper -> var = 13;
    fi;
}

proctype pick_two_balls() {
    byte idx;
    byte idy;

    my_select(idx, TOTAL_BALLS - 1);
    my_select(idy, TOTAL_BALLS - 2);

    printf("Initial picks:\n")

    printf("\tpicked %d in [0, %d]\n", idx, TOTAL_BALLS - 1);
    printf("\tpicked %d in [0, %d]\n", idy, TOTAL_BALLS - 2);

    idy = ((idx + 1) + idy) % (TOTAL_BALLS);

    printf("Adjusted picks:\n");

    printf("\tball #01 at index %d\n", idx);
    printf("\tball #02 at index %d\n", idy);

    printf("Final Balls:\n");

    if
        :: box[idx]  -> printf("\tbox[%d] = black\n", idx);
        :: !box[idx] -> printf("\tbox[%d] = white\n", idx);
    fi;

    if
        :: box[idy]  -> printf("\tbox[%d] = black\n", idy);
        :: !box[idy] -> printf("\tbox[%d] = white\n", idy);
    fi;
}

init {
    byte idx = 0;
    byte todo = BLACK_BALLS;

    do  // not guaranteed to terminate!
        :: todo > 0 ->
            my_select(idx, TOTAL_BALLS - 1) ->
            if
                :: box[idx] ->
                    skip;
                :: else ->
                    box[idx] = true;
                    todo = todo - 1;
            fi;
        :: else ->
            break;
    od;

    for (idx: 0 .. TOTAL_BALLS - 1) {
        if
            :: box[idx] ->
                printf("box[%d] = black\n", idx);
            :: !box[idx] ->
                printf("box[%d] = white\n", idx);
        fi;
    }
    run pick_two_balls();
}
```

**Output:**

```
~$ spin p.pml 
      box[0] = white
      box[1] = black
      box[2] = white
      box[3] = white
      box[4] = white
      box[5] = white
      box[6] = white
      box[7] = white
      box[8] = white
      box[9] = white
      box[10] = white
      box[11] = black
      box[12] = black
      box[13] = black
          Initial picks:
            picked 9 in [0, 13]
            picked 7 in [0, 12]
          Adjusted picks:
            ball #01 at index 9
            ball #02 at index 3
          Final Balls:
            box[9] = white
            box[3] = white
2 processes created
```

---

**Note #1:** in normal circumnstances, I would have used the [`select`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/select.html) statement instead of writing my own `my_select(var, upper)` function. However, [`select`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/select.html) does not guarantee that the value assigned to `var` is picked with a **uniform distribution**, and I thought this could be an issue for you.

---

**Note #2:** when you need to extract more than a pair of indexes, the mathematical expression above is not helpful. However, you can apply the same principle in a mechanical sense: maintain `used_indexes` as a support array of bools, whereby location `k` is `true` if it is used by some index. Each time you pick a new index `i`, you start counting the empty cells from the beginning of the array, and decrease `i` by one. As soon as `i = 0` you have the *"real index"* `j` that should be used in the original array, so you mark that location as used in `used_indexes`.